# Why doesn't the Java CLI react when I try to increase heap space?

Tags: java, ubuntu, heap-memory

I'm trying to increase the jvm heap space memory in an ubuntu system. When I run the command

```
java -Xmx2000m
```

The output it gives is LITERALLY the exact same as the output it gives you when you just type

```
java
```

into the command line. I.E. it gives a description of how to use the java CLI, but refuses to acknowledge the fact that I told it to do something. It doesn't give me a failure message, yet when I run

```
java -XshowSettings
```

it reveals that the max heap space size has not been changed.

How can I get the java CLI to stop acting like a politician in a tv interview, and to start replying to what I tell it to do so I know what to change about what I'm doing?

Comment: You don't tell Java what to do, you don't give the name of something to execute. So it simply exits.

Comment: @Marged yeah I thought that running this command line expression was supposed to change the overall default settings for JVMs; didn't realize the settings were specific to one program execution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run both parameters within a single invocation, as they are scoped to the JVM you are creating on the run:

```
java -Xmx2000m -XshowSettings
```

**Output** (cut to the bare minimum for this answer)

```
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size: 1.95G
```

If you need your memory parameters set as a global default, you can use the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable.

For instance:

```
set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx2000m
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Any idea why java doesn't give a message about why my command was invalid? Also, when I do something like java -Xmx2000m does that only apply that setting to the program I run in that command line call? If so, I think I'll use your command for setting a global default.

Comment: @VijayRamamurthy both your previous commands were valid, they just didn't do what you expected :) And yes, as I state in my answer, the command-line parameters are contextual to the JVM creation within that command line. If you need a global default, you need to set it explicitly as such.

Comment: Is there anything else I need to do when i change the global default heap size? When I run `set JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2000m` and then run `java -XshowSettings` I still get that the Max. Heap Size hasn't changed.

Comment: @VijayRamamurthy after a quick search, I think you need to set `_JAVA_OPTIONS` for the global default. `JAVA_OPTS` is just a placeholder for when you invoke java, hence the syntax would still require `java $JAVA_OPTS etc.`.